# Rename excel sheets in R studio

Tags: r, writexl

I have one spreadsheet with 4 sheets in it, and I want to rename the sheets when I export the file from R.

How can I do it- I can't download XLConnect library.

This is what I have so far:

```
sheets <- list(sheet1 = Top_Balances, sheet2 = Over_60, sheet3 = CI, sheet4 = CL)
write_xlsx(sheets, "C:/Users/Desktop/R/April Aging.xlsx")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, see here https://github.com/ropensci/writexl/issues/18

```
write_xlsx(list(sheet1 = Top_Balances, sheet2 = Over_60, sheet3 = CI, sheet4 = CL))
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, this is what I did:                     
```sheets <- list(Top_Balances = Top_Balances, Over_60_PD = Over_60_PD, Over_CI = Over_CI, Over_CL = Over_CL)
write_xlsx(sheets, "C:/Users/Adi.Koren/Desktop/R/April AR Aging.xlsx")```